# Something is wrong with /review and first questions or I am confused

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

So I was going through /review first question list

> These are the first questions a new user has ever asked on Web Applications.

and realized, hey ... that's my question

[How can I "unsubscribe" from a message thread on Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4223/how-can-i-unsubscribe-from-a-message-thread-on-facebook)

asked Jul 20 '10 at 0:45

But... that's not my first question.

This is:

[How do I get the phone numbers of my Facebook Friends?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-do-i-get-the-phone-numbers-of-my-facebook-friends)

asked Jun 30 '10 at 20:32

The screenshot for I don't think I can replicate this after I refresh that page.

[image: My first post but not really]

Comment: Thanks so much for catching this ... so happy the review path is finally being used

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That would be this guys fault https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/4223/jess-riedel .. notice his user id ... it is 4233 just like your question ... horrible bug ...

I was just reading through the query I wrote, my only explanation for this failure is bad meds on my side.

Comment: The great western poet John Francis Bongiovi, Jr once wrote, "bad medicine/is what I need/bad, bad/medicine".

Comment: @jonsca thanks :-) A Bon Jovi reference just bought me an extra hour on the computer from the wife! Woot!